# How to speed Haskell IO with buffering?

Tags: performance, haskell, io, buffering

I read about IO buffering in the "Real World Haskell" (ch. 7, p. 189), and tried to test, how different buffering size affects the performance.

```
import System.IO
import Data.Time.Clock
import Data.Char(toUpper)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  hInp <- openFile "bigFile.txt" ReadMode
  let bufferSize = truncate $ 2**10
  hSetBuffering hInp (BlockBuffering (Just bufferSize))
  bufferMode <- hGetBuffering hInp
  putStrLn $ "Current buffering mode: " ++ (show bufferMode)

  startTime <- getCurrentTime
  inp <- hGetContents hInp
  writeFile "processed.txt" (map toUpper inp)
  hClose hInp
  finishTime <- getCurrentTime
  print $ diffUTCTime finishTime startTime
  return ()
```

Then I created a "bigFile.txt"

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 96M янв.  26 09:49 bigFile.txt
```

and run my program against this file, with different buffer size:

```
Current buffering mode: BlockBuffering (Just 32)
9.744967s   

Current buffering mode: BlockBuffering (Just 1024)
9.667924s                                      

Current buffering mode: BlockBuffering (Just 1048576)
9.494807s    

Current buffering mode: BlockBuffering (Just 1073741824)
9.792453s
```

But the program running time is almost the same. Is it normal, or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On a modern OS it is likely that the buffer size has little effect on reading a file linearly due to 1) read-ahead performed by the kernel and 2) the file might already be in the page cache if you have already read the file recently.

Here is a program which measures the effect of buffering on writes. Typical results are:

```
$ ./mkbigfile 32      -- 12.864733s
$ ./mkbigfile 64      --  9.668272s
$ ./mkbigfile 128     --  6.993664s
$ ./mkbigfile 512     --  4.130989s
$ ./mkbigfile 1024    --  3.536652s
$ ./mkbigfile 16384   --  3.055403s
$ ./mkbigfile 1000000 --  3.004879s
```

Source:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Control.Monad
import System.IO
import System.Environment
import Data.Time.Clock

main = do
  (arg:_) <- getArgs
  let size = read arg
  let bs = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
      n = 96000000 `div` (length bs)
  h <- openFile "bigFile.txt" WriteMode
  hSetBuffering h (BlockBuffering (Just size))
  startTime <- getCurrentTime
  replicateM_ n $ hPutStrLn h bs
  hClose h
  finishTime <- getCurrentTime
  print $ diffUTCTime finishTime startTime
  return ()
```

Comment: So why didn't the OP see that kind of difference in his program?

Comment: The OP's program sets the buffering on a read handle, not the write handle.

Comment: Even if the kernel has something buffered, don't you still need a system call to read it?

Comment: Sure, but the point is that adding another level of buffering (which is what hSetBuffering controls) for reads isn't necessarily going to speed things up.