# Haskell getContents wait for EOF

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I want to wait until user input terminates with EOF and then output it all whole. Isn't that what `getContents` supposed to do? The following code outputs each time user hits enter, what am I doing wrong?

```
import System.IO

main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  contents <- getContents
  putStrLn contents
```

Comment: You'd be better of using [`isEOF`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/System-IO.html#v:isEOF), `getContents` lazily returns the contents, which means if your processing is also lazy you'll get chunks of input as it's available.  Also, I think you mean `NoBuffering`, not `NoneBuffering`.

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but I think you meant to set buffering for `stdin`, not `stdout`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that `getContents` is an instances of **Lazy IO**. This means that `getContents` produces a thunk that can be evaluated like a normal Haskell value, and only does the relevant IO *when it's forced*.

`contents` is a lazy list that `putStr` tries to print, which forces the list and causes `getContents` to read as much as it can. `putStr` then prints everything that's forced, and continues trying to force the rest of the list until it hits `[]`. As `getContents` can read more and more of the stream—the exact behavior depends on buffering—`putStr` can print more and more of it immediately, giving you the behavior you see.

While this behavior is useful for very simple scripts, it ties in Haskell's evaluation order into *observable* effects—something it was never meant to do. This means that controlling exactly when parts of `contents` get printed is awkward because you have to break the normal Haskell abstraction and understand exactly how things are getting evaluated.

This leads to some potentially unintuitive behavior. For example, if you try to get the length of the input—and actually *use* it—the list is forced before you get to printing it, giving you the behavior you want:

```
main = do
  contents <- getContents
  let n = length contents
  print n
  putStr contents
```

but if you move the `print n` after the `putStr`, you go back to the original behavior because `n` does not get forced until *after* printing the input (even though `n` still got *defined* before `putStr` was used):

```
main = do
  contents <- getContents
  let n = length contents
  putStr contents
  print n
```

Normally, this sort of thing is not a problem because it won't change the *behavior* of your code (although it can affect performance). Lazy IO just brings it into the realm of correctness by piercing the abstraction layer.

This also gives us a hint on how we can fix your issue: we need some way of forcing `contents` before printing it. As we saw, we can do this with `length` because `length` needs to traverse the whole list before computing its result. Instead of printing it, we can use `seq` which forces the lefthand expression to be evaluated at the same time as the righthand one, but throws away the actual value:

```
main = do
  contents <- getContents
  let n = length contents
  n `seq` putStr contents
```

At the same time, this is still a bit ugly because we're using `length` just to traverse the list, not because we actually care about it. What we would really like is a function that *just* traverses the list enough to evaluate it, without doing anything else. Happily, this is exactly what `deepseq` does (for many data structures, not just lists):

```
import Control.DeepSeq
import System.IO

main = do
  contents <- getContents
  contents `deepseq` putStr contents
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a problem of lazy I/O. One simple solution is to use strict I/O, such as via ByteStrings:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as S

main :: IO ()
main = S.getContents >>= S.putStr
```

Comment: Tikhon's answer is far more complete than mine, it should be accepted. I'll leave mine in place since it gives what I think is a more canonical solution to the problem (using strict ByteStrings instead of forcing a lazy thunk).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the replacement functions from the `strict` package [(link)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict-0.3.2/docs/System-IO-Strict.html):

```
import qualified System.IO.Strict as S

main = do
  contents <- S.getContents
  putStrLn contents
```

Note that for reading there isn't a need to set buffering. Buffering really only helps when writing to files. See this answer [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28146677/866915) for more details.

The definition of the strict version of `hGetContents` in System.IO.Strict is pretty simple:

```
hGetContents    :: IO.Handle -> IO.IO String
hGetContents h  = IO.hGetContents h >>= \s -> length s `seq` return s
```

I.e., it forces everything to read into memory by calling `length` on the string returned by the standard/lazy version of `hGetContents`.